# Is there a direct way (at the lower level) to do $('#id')?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-selectors

I mostly call jQuery elements by the id of the DOM object using the `$('#id')` syntax. I think that this goes through the selector algorithm, and spends some time on that process.

I was wondering if there is a way to dig into that function and access jQuery objects from the id of the DOM in a more direct way (at the lower level) to improve performance. Will it worth doing so? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: `$(document.getElementById('id'));` I believe this works.

Comment: var $id = document.getElementById; $($id('id'));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going native will always be faster / more direct:

```
var id = document.getElementById("id");
```

But you will loose the benefits of wrapping your object in a jQuery wrapper.

You can also do :

```
$(document.getElementById("id"))
```

That way you are passing in the direct object rather than performing a lookup on the dom.

Answer (score 4):

When you pass jQuery a single, lone ID selector, [it automatically skips any selector processing and calls `document.getElementById()` directly](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector). It's only when the selector string consists of anything *more* than an ID selector that it always treats it like a selector (this includes selectors like `div#id`, `.class#id`, or even `#wrapper #id`).

In most cases, this is something you don't have to worry about, since jQuery already does a lot of optimization for you. But if you're paranoid and want to remove every hair and every ounce of any possible overhead, see [cookie monster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22941443/is-there-a-direct-way-at-the-lower-level-to-do-id/22941550#22941550).

Comment: To put this into context, in relation to the actual source code, it's the very first check within Sizzle: https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/src/sizzle.js#L206

Comment: Your answer seems to suggest that there is not much room for improvement, but [this site](http://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-jquery-id/44) introduced to me by SNM's answer indicates that `$(document.getElementById('id'))` is (probably significantly) faster than `$('#id')`.

Comment: @MackieeE: jQuery actually [bypasses Sizzle](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9.1/src/core.js#L151-L153) by doing its own test with [this regex](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9.1/src/core.js#L54-L57).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to improve performance, keep a jQuery object that's used for single node synchronous operations

```
var _id = $(document);
```

---

Then update its `0` property when you need to fetch by ID.

```
_id[0] = document.getElementById("id");

_id.css(...);
```

---

This eliminates the vast majority of its overhead. Because JS is single threaded, you can reuse this object wherever needed. But if you want to do some operation in a `setTimeout()`, you should probably just create a new object to be safe.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Yes. By passing `document` to the initial object, it has its `.length` set at `1`. Beyond that, jQuery has no memory of the initial set. The only hangup could be if you originally used a selector to create the object. Then its `.selector` would be set. Not sure if that would cause a problem, but passing `document` should avoid it anyway.

Comment: Is this actually doing `[document.getElementById("id")]`?

Comment: @sawa: A jQuery object is an Array-like object. It's an object that stores the nodes at numeric indices. All we're doing here is updating the node at index `0` in order to reuse the object. So there isn't any Array or any other object being created. Just a lookup.

Comment: ...here's a performance test. http://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-jquery-id/115 Basically the same speed as native.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I see it is fast. But I may need to handle more than one object at a time. In that case, is there a way to apply this?

Comment: @sawa: You could cache several objects, or just ditch jQuery altogether if you're really concerned about performance. All depends on what you need. This approach is especially useful for holding `this` in event handlers, since you can name it `_this`, and do `_this[0] = this` when needed.

Comment: Thanks for the help. For the moment, I will use xCNPx and scott (in the comment)'s solution. Your answer is much faster, but I need to do some adjustment. I will be thinking about it.

Comment: You're welcome. It isn't right for every situation, but can help when convenient to use.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) like this

```
var name = document.getElementById('id');
```

Comment: Are you sure that gives a jQuery object?

Comment: No, it won't but `$(document.getElementById('id'))` will, or `$(name)`

Comment: no, but you can transform it into a jQuery object with the standard $()

Comment: I don't think so, this is just javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Actually.... this will depend on the browser u will be using to run the script.... here i did some dig on the internet..... i found a test result on this topic.....

Here is the [Site](http://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-jquery-id/44)

As to them JQuery selectors are faster than the native JS code.

Comment: *"...JQuery selectors are faster than the native JS code"* That's silly. jQuery is slower because it has overhead on top of the same native code that would be used. Your jsPerf shows that jQuery is much, much slower than native `getElementById`.

Comment: well.... yeah that's true... Jquery is build on the native JS... but most of the browsers today have optimize there environments to run the  JQuery much faster... just look at the test charts in the site i posted... Jquery really did lesser operations than Native js

Comment: As cookie monster comments, your description is not accurate, but the link helped. Thanks for it.